# Phabricator Arcanist arc land vs arc amend

Tags: git, phabricator

I am using Phabricator and Arcanist for code reviews in my team. The 'arc land' command is awesome, but there is one scenario where it doesn't work for us.

We have a single xml file, that contains a linked list (each element refers to a previous element). We don't make changes to this file very often, but once in a while we do. If two people make changes at the same time a "silent conflict" occurs, meaning that the linked list is broken because both new elements link to the same previous element. This is not very difficult to resolve. But no merge conflict is raised by git.

So when we run arc land, the incorrect xml file is automatically pushed. We don't want that.

Would the correct action be to use arc amend, and then resolve that conflict manually followed by a git push (like we do today without any hassle), or how would you suggest moving forward with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some possible ideas:

- You can `arc land --hold` to stop before the `git push` is run and inspect the changes, then run `git push` manually.
- You can add a local Git pre-commit hook to validate the XML file before Git allows the commit.
- You can add a pre-receive hook on the server to validate the XML file before it is pushed to the remote.
- You can override Git's merge behavior using a `merge` directive in `gitattributes`, and replace the default merge with one which gets it right (or fails to merge).
- You could try to replace the XML file with data in some format which doesn't have these undesirable merge properties, since this problem is a general one.
- You could force the merge to fail by including some string in the file which would always conflict. For example, add an attribute like `lastNode="whatever"` to the container element (i.e., always on line 1 or whatever), so that two edits would always conflict on that line by naming different last nodes (to make sure this was edited, you could check that the `lastNode` was correct at runtime). If the file is automatically generated, you could simply put a random number in a comment on a well-known line.

Comment: Awesome! `arc land --hold` is what makes sense right now. A pre-receive hook (too many different local setups to rely on a pre-commit hook), that validates the XML file is the logical next step. This has never been a big problem before, since the file is manually edited and easily understood and fixed by even new employees without any introduction. But with arc land I see people forgetting this.